# Same value returned when using find and rfind on a string in Python 3.7.0 (using idle)

Tags: python, string, find

Novice user of Python and Stack Overflow - first question

I am perplexed of why I am getting same value for find and rfind (Python 3.7.0) for the following:

```
>>> string="ooook"
>>> string.rfind('k')             
4
>>> string.find('k')             
4
```

One of these should be 0, shouldn't it?

-Has rfind changed in later versions of Python?

-Am I supposed to import something to use find and rfind?

-Local issue with my PC?

Comment: Only one `k` at index `4`. Both `find` and `rfind` should give `4`. What's wrong?

Comment: Why were you expecting a 0?

Comment: `rfind(char)` gives the index of the rightmost occurance of that char. Note that you are not indexing from right.

Comment: Thank you.  Based on your answers, I figured out what find and rfind actually do, which I initially misunderstood.  Thanks.  (Now that I realize it, I was trying to get number of characters away from the beginning and start of the string that the k occurs, which will require extra step)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [ipython](http://ipython.org/) (*I can warmly recommend*) you can type `??` before a command in order to see its docstring.

Doing so for `string.rfind`:

> Docstring:
>
> S.rfind(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
>
> Return the **highest index in S where substring sub is found**,
>   such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>
> Return -1 on failure.
>
> Type:      builtin_function_or_method

and for `string.find`:

> Docstring:
>
> S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
>
> Return the **lowest index in S where substring sub is found**,
>   such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>
> Return -1 on failure.
>
> Type:      builtin_function_or_method

*I took the liberty to highlight the important parts.*

What it means is that both will return the same index if there is only one substring (i.e. `'k'` in your case) found.

If you are still unsure about how `str.rfind` and `str.find` differ from each other, try the same thing with:

```
string = 'kooook'
```

*Hope that helps and happy coding!*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `rfind()` do the same as `find()`, but return the last index.

Being only one 'k', the two of the return the same.
With 'o', the result will be different.